# Android BLE ScanCallback LOW LATENCY

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I’m building BLE Android.
My application scan for BLE devices with background service 24/7 (this is essential for my app) with SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER as settings.
When i find devices that are related to my app i switch to SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY because at this point every 1 second count for my app.
With SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY i'm receiving ScanCallback intensively but at some point like when device in sleep mode i’m receiving like 10-11 callback intensively then a pause of 3-4s then the callbacks again.

This 3-4s delay/pause isn’t helping my app at all.

Is it possible to have  intensive ScanCallback even if the device is in sleep or doze mode?

Thanks.

Log when screen on:

05-25 09:26:27.121 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:27.161 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn 
:true

05-25 09:26:27.211 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:27.251 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:27.301 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

...intensive ScanCallback

05-25 09:26:41.101 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:41.151 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:41.201 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:41.251 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:41.291 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:41.341 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

05-25 09:26:41.391 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :true

Log when screen off:

05-25 09:26:50.141 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.191 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.221 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.271 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.301 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.351 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.401 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.441 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.501 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.531 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.581 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:50.631 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

---> no Callback 5s

05-25 09:26:55.151 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.201 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.251 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.301 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.341 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.381 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.421 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.481 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.521 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.571 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

05-25 09:26:55.611 14564-14564/? I/TAG_BLE: BLE onScanResult - isScreenOn :false

Comment: Related https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_app_standby and https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases

Comment: Do you have a foreground service running in your app process? If you haven't you should have one if you need to have a BLE scanning in the background; otherwise it's a chance that the app gets terminated after a while.

Comment: No i don't have foreground service i'm using STICKY background service. The issue is not there my service was not killed (i'm assuring the service will not be killed).I'm always receiving ScanCallback callbacks but some time not as much as i want.For example when the screen is unlocked i'm receive intensive ScanCallback once it's locked i'm still receiving callbacks but there is 3-4s pause in between.

Comment: What Android version are you running? Could you try make it a foreground service and see what happens? Foreground services are not affected by doze mode.

Comment: I have the same result with foreground service.My initial test was with galaxy S6  Android 6.0.1 when the screen unlocked i'm having intensive ScanCallback but once it's locked i'm having 4-5s pause between callbacks it's the same result when i force the Idle mode. But with Nexus 7.0 i'm always having intensive callbacks even in Idle mode.. I'm very confused at this point..

Answer (score 0):

Different manufacturers use different Bluetooth chips. Therefore, such behavior is very possible. Have you tried restarting the scan every second or so? Just starting and stopping it.

Comment: I tried that but some time i don't get callback when restarting the scan.As a result i have  3-4s without callback also.